# UIView title causing constraints problem XIB Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have one UITabBarController that has 5x child UIViewControllers, each of which is a UINavigationViewController.

For a UIView in any of the UINavigationControllers, If I set the title in viewDidLoad via

```
self.title=@"TITLE";
```

Then I get the following unsatisfied constraint error

```
2020-05-28 14:21:23.055778+0100 Datum Connect[6515:10336196] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
```

(
    "= UILayoutGuide:0x600001968540'TitleView(0x7fa0a710a390)'.top   (active)>",
    ""
)

There are no constraints set up in my XIB. 
This is fairly old (~2013) code so there's probably a deprecation issue somewhere with the autogenerated layouts...?

But if I use

```
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = @"TITLE";
or
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title=@"TITLE";
or
self.navigationController.title=@"TITLE";
```

There is no the constraints problem, but the TITLE text doesn't appear either, just the empty nav bar.

Comment: You *"have a UIView with a UITabBarController"*? And you're trying to set the `.title` for the NavigationBar? I think you need to clarify what you are actually doing...

Comment: It has 5x tabs and one of the tabs also has a UINavigationController so the design has a Nav Bar at the top for all the tabs (I am not the designer).  self.navigationController.navigationItem.title also gives the same constraint error.

Comment: Still not quite clear... if only *ONE* tab holds a `UINavigationController`, how is that Nav Bar at the top of all the tabs? Really tough to offer a solution when it's not clear what your View / Controller hierarchy is.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your help, I have edited, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: You'll still need to provide more details. Essentially, you've said *"I have a XIB from an old project, and I get an auto-layout error. What is wrong?"* Pretty unlikely anyone can guess. Try to put together a [mre].

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure about your issue but if the view has no constraints then there will be no warnings.

Try to add this

```
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

to your view.